# VPN Kill switch doesn't work with Tor Traffic

Tags: linux, vpn, tor, openvpn

Always, when I try to run kill switch for VPN my Tor Browser stops working and I am not sure why it happened. I am not good in firewalls and port forwarding but I would like to learn. 
I have configuration: VPN - Whonix Gateway - Whonix Workstation. I am using Fedora 29 and my VPN is NordVPN(setup on OpenVPN).How can I configure firewall that killswitch will allow TOR like in my configuration(VPN - Whonix Gateway - Whonix Workstation). I am not sure what should I do, shoul I some forwarding?

I have tried 3 solutions:

Firewalld - does not work at all. After I run this my network stop working:

```
sudo firewall-cmd --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter FORWARD 0 -o tun+ -j ACCEPT
sudo firewall-cmd --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter FORWARD 0 -i tun+ -j ACCEPT

sudo firewall-cmd --direct --add-rule ipv6 filter INPUT 0 -j DROP
sudo firewall-cmd --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter INPUT 0 -i lo -j ACCEPT
sudo firewall-cmd --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter INPUT 1 -i tun+ -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
sudo firewall-cmd --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter INPUT 999 -j DROP

sudo firewall-cmd --direct --add-rule ipv6 filter OUTPUT 0 -j DROP
sudo firewall-cmd --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter OUTPUT 0 -o lo -j ACCEPT
sudo firewall-cmd --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter OUTPUT 0 -o tun+ -j ACCEPT
sudo firewall-cmd --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter OUTPUT 1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
sudo firewall-cmd --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter OUTPUT 999 -j DROP
```

UFW - works fine with VPN, when I turn on Whonix Gateway it stop working. It seems that kill switch start and it turn off my network:

```
sudo ufw reset
sudo ufw default deny incoming
sudo ufw default deny outgoing
sudo ufw allow out on tun0 from any to any
sudo ufw enable
```

I tried vpndemon - I choose to terminate 'NetworkManager' but it does not work. It works when I enter firefox but it is not helpful.

Comment: This questions is not about security, but about VPN configuration. I am voting to move it.

Comment: where should I ask then?

Comment: Superuser or ServerFault. Mods will move it, don't worry.